# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar solo las columnas que contengan al menos un dato?

Tags: r, dplyr

Tengo un data frame llamado `Tabla`, el cuál tiene varias columnas que no tienen ningún dato (todos son NA). ¿Hay alguna manera de seleccionar únicamente aquellas columnas que contengan al menos un dato?

En la imagen de ejemplo, el nombre de columna encerrado en un círculo no contiene ningún dato, y como esa columna tengo muchas.

[image: Tabla con columnas que en su totalidad son NA]

Comment: Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con R base puedes contar la cantidad de `NA` que tienes en cada columna y si este número es igual a la cantidad de filas, entonces podemos asumir que la columna o variable no tiene datos. Por ejemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(con_datos=c(NA,NA, 1),
                 solo_na=c(NA,NA,NA))
df
  con_datos solo_na
1        NA      NA
2        NA      NA
3         1      NA
```

Es claro que podemos ignorar la columna `solo_na`:

```
df[,!colSums(is.na(df)) == nrow(df), drop=FALSE]

  con_datos
1        NA
2        NA
3         1
```

Comment: Una vez que entendí tu código me pareció puro y claro, simplemente excelente. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Una versión usando `tidyverse`

Definiendo una función auxiliar que entregue verdadero si existe algún valor que no sea NA

```
library(tidyverse)
no_na <- function(x) any(!is.na(x))

df2 <- df %>% 
    select(where(no_na))
```

Esto seleccionará todas las columnas donde existe algún valor valido.

Comment: Funcionó muy bien, muchas gracias